# Removing nonsense words in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I want to remove nonsense words in my dataset.

I tried which I saw StackOverflow something like this:

```
import nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "Io andiamo to the beach with my amico."
" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
     if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

But now since I have a dataframe how do i iterate it over the whole column.

I tried something like this:

```
import nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = df['Chats']
df['Chats'] = df['Chats'].apply(lambda w:" ".join(w for w in 
nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
     if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha()))
```

But I am getting an error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: The full traceback should show which part of your code is at fault.

Comment: `isalpha` or `lower` are passed something that isn't a string.

Comment: @cdarke, ya, the error is in isalpha(). Can you suggest me what code should I be writting instead??

Comment: You also get a line number with that error. Please make sure to [edit] and add everything useful to others willing to help you.

Comment: @Questions:  if you knew that then why didn't you tell us in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will generate a column `Clean` that applies your function to the column `Chats`

```
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

def clean_sent(sent):
    return " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
     if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())

df['Clean'] = df['Chats'].apply(clean_sent)
```

To update the `Chats` column itself, you can overwrite it using the original column:

```
df['Chats'] = df['Chats'].apply(clean_sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

df['Chats'] = [re.sub('\n', '', x) for x in df['Chats']]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], and try to *explain* code in answers - this is not simply a code-writing service (if you are interested in just writing code like that, consider going somewhere that you would at least get paid for it). Specifically, describe the approach your code takes, and *how* it solves the problem.